# Most performant way to test if timestamp is in range

Tags: mysql, performance, time-series, data-analysis, bigdata

I want to know what is the most performant way of testing if a timestamp is in range between to dates considering a big growing datastore.

**The setup**

Basically i have to tables. One **(A)** for sensor data where density is per minute and one **(B)** table where only changes are monitored.

Table **A** is the table where all sensor data is stored per minute and its growing constantly. Its a requirement that the data ist stored in this density and can not be compressed.

```
+-----------+------------------------+-------+
| sensor_id |        datetime        | value |
+-----------+------------------------+-------+
|         1 |    2016-08-22 17:26:00 |    23 |
|         1 |    2016-08-22 17:27:00 |     5 |
|         1 |    2016-08-22 17:28:00 |    12 |
|         1 |    2016-08-22 17:29:00 |     0 |
|         1 |    2016-08-22 17:30:00 |   150 |
|         1 |    2016-08-22 17:31:00 |     9 |
+-----------+------------------------+-------+
```

Table **B** is the table where all state changes from the sensors are monitored. These events can occur randomly and are not per minute.

```
+-----------+------------------------+----------+
| sensor_id |        datetime        |  state   |
+-----------+------------------------+----------+
|         1 |    2016-08-22 17:26:00 | up       |
|         1 |    2016-08-22 17:29:00 | down     |
|         1 |    2016-08-22 17:31:00 | shutdown |
+-----------+------------------------+----------+
```

**The result**

Now i want to map for each data in table A the corresponding state from table B which looks like

```
+-----------+------------------------+-------+----------+
| sensor_id |        datetime        | value |  state   |
+-----------+------------------------+-------+----------+
|         1 |    2016-08-22 17:26:00 |    23 | up       |
|         1 |    2016-08-22 17:27:00 |     5 | up       |
|         1 |    2016-08-22 17:28:00 |    12 | up       |
|         1 |    2016-08-22 17:29:00 |     0 | down     |
|         1 |    2016-08-22 17:30:00 |   150 | down     |
|         1 |    2016-08-22 17:31:00 |     9 | shutdown |
+-----------+------------------------+-------+----------+
```

**The problem**

Data in both tables is constantly growing because of multiple sensors. For example keeping all values for just one month and one single sensor would result in **43200** data points. Increasing the number of sensors also increases the number of data points in both tables which makes the mapping slower and slower.

So whats the best way to check if a timestamp from table A is between a state from table B when my store is growing up to millions of data points? I would have to take each single point from A and look up the matching state from table B which can also have millions of data points and my guess is that this become very slow and unefficient. I need to do this in real time for analytics!

Thx

Comment: Do you know about indexes?

Comment: I am using them but this discussion should be more in generel terms of this problem then the selection of the data store.

Comment: You are talking about a process that, whatever you do, will grow with the number of records in the table. An alternative would be to have an extra table with one record for each sensor and that is updated whenever the state of the sensor changes. This way, the number of records of the scanned table will stay stable and the performance of the query will hence be predictable.

Comment: I came up with a similar solution like u said but i was unsure if i should do it on the storage level or if there is any exisiting mathematical algorithm that i can use at the software level. I think this is a generel problem which many people have entering the world of big data.

Comment: How do we know that 26:00 is 'up'?

Comment: The default state if there isn't any before is always up

Comment: Confused. Is it because the default state is always up, or because you changed the data set?

Comment: I changed it recently to make it better understandable. Sorry for that. Now the mapping is easier to read :)

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

Answer (score 0):

Well, based upon the current data set, the following appears to be valid - although I wonder both whether you've over-simplified the problem, and whether I've over-cooked the solution.

```
SELECT x.*
     , y.state -- or possibly COALESCE(y.state,'up') state
  FROM
     ( SELECT a.*
            , MAX(b.datetime) max_datetime
         FROM table_a a 
         LEFT 
         JOIN table_b b 
           ON b.sensor_id = a.sensor_id 
          AND b.datetime <= a.datetime 
        GROUP 
           BY a.sensor_id,a.datetime
     ) x
  LEFT
  JOIN table_b y
    ON y.sensor_id = x.sensor_id
   AND y.datetime = x.max_datetime;
```

Comment: Will give it a try